# Scala: Read some data of an Enumerator[T] and return the remaining Enumerator[T]

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

I am using the asynchronous I/O library of the playframework which uses Iteratees and Enumerators. I now have an Iterator[T] as data sink (for simplification say it's an Iterator[Byte] which stores its content into a file). This Iterator[Byte] is passed to the function which handles the writing.

But before writing I want to add some statistical information at the file begin (for simplification say it's one Byte), so I transfer the iterator the following way before passing it to the write function:

```
def write(value: Byte, output: Iteratee[Byte]): Iteratee[Byte] =
    Iteratee.flatten(output.feed(Input.El(value)))
```

When I now read the stored file from the disk, I get an Enumerator[Byte] for it.
At first I want to read and remove the additional data and then I want to pass the rest of the Enumerator[Byte] to a function which handles the reading.
So I also need to transform the enumerator:

```
def read(input: Enumerator[Byte]): (Byte, Enumerator[Byte]) = {
   val firstEnumeratorEntry = ...
   val remainingEnumerator = ...
   (firstEnumeratorEntry, remainingEnumerator)
}
```

But I have no idea, how to do this. How can I read some bytes from an Enumerator and get the remaining Enumerator?

Replacing Iteratee[Byte] with OutputStream and Enumerator[Byte] with InputStream, this would be very easy:

```
def write(value: Byte, output: OutputStream) = {
    output.write(value)
    output
}
def read(input: InputStream) = (input.read,input)
```

But I need the asynchronous I/O of the play framework.

Comment: mmmmh, what I'm thinking (but need some check) is that having the `read` method returning `(Byte, Enumerator[Byte])` breaks the `Async`.
Because everything is based on Iteratee, Enumeratee, Enumerator which are like 'hey I'll promise to give or map or produce something'. However, when you say `Byte`... you've already something.
Hence what I was thinking... we're on two different timelines.

Comment: I'd be satisfied with (Promise[Byte],Enumerator[Byte])

Comment: I think that it should be done within using the `fold` method of the `Iteratee` companion. So creating an Iteratee holding a state which might be something like `(Option[Byte], Array[Byte])`. And you start with `(None, [])`

Comment: Actually when I was using `Byte` it's not that you have too. You must probably use the transformed types like maybe `(Option[Int], List[Entry])` or what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve this by folding within the `Iteratee` and an appropriate (kind-of) State accumulator (a tuple here)

I go read the `routes` file, the first byte will be read as a `Char` and the other will be appended to a `String` as UTF-8 bytestrings.

```
  def index = Action {
    /*let's do everything asyncly*/
    Async {
      /*for comprehension for read-friendly*/
      for (
        i <- read; /*read the file */
        (r:(Option[Char], String)) <- i.run /*"create" the related Promise and run it*/
      ) yield Ok("first : " + r._1.get + "\n" + "rest" + r._2) /* map the Promised result in a correct Request's Result*/
    }
  }


  def read = {
    //get the routes file in an Enumerator
    val file: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromFile(Play.getFile("/conf/routes"))

    //apply the enumerator with an Iteratee that folds the data as wished
    file(Iteratee.fold((None, ""):(Option[Char], String)) { (acc, b) =>
       acc._1 match {
         /*on the first chunk*/ case None => (Some(b(0).toChar), acc._2 + new String(b.tail, Charset.forName("utf-8")))
         /*on other chunks*/ case x => (x, acc._2 + new String(b, Charset.forName("utf-8")))
       }
    })

  }
```

**EDIT**

I found yet another way using `Enumeratee` but it needs to create 2 `Enumerator` s (one short lived). However is it a bit more elegant. We use a "kind-of" Enumeratee but the `Traversal` one which works at a finer level than Enumeratee (chunck level).
We use `take` 1 that will take only 1 byte and then close the stream. On the other one, we use `drop` that simply drops the first byte (because we're using a Enumerator[Array[Byte]])

Furthermore, now `read2` has a signature much more closer than what you wished, because it returns 2 enumerators (not so far from Promise, Enumerator)

```
def index = Action {
  Async {
    val (first, rest) = read2
    val enee = Enumeratee.map[Array[Byte]] {bs => new String(bs, Charset.forName("utf-8"))}

    def useEnee(enumor:Enumerator[Array[Byte]]) = Iteratee.flatten(enumor &> enee |>> Iteratee.consume[String]()).run.asInstanceOf[Promise[String]]

    for {
      f <- useEnee(first);
      r <- useEnee(rest)
    } yield Ok("first : " + f + "\n" + "rest" + r)
  }
}

def read2 = {
  def create = Enumerator.fromFile(Play.getFile("/conf/routes"))

  val file: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = create
  val file2: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = create

  (file &> Traversable.take[Array[Byte]](1), file2 &> Traversable.drop[Array[Byte]](1))

}
```

Comment: Why do I need the second file enumerator? Aren't enumerators immutable functional objects? So I could just use the same enumerator for both enumeratees?

Comment: Yes, but it's probably due to the fact the underlying InputStream isn't... TO be checked futher

Comment: You're correct. Enumerator.fromFile uses fromStream and Enumerator.fromStream is just implemented via a Enumerator.fromCallback which stores a (mutable!) FileInputStream. To be useable in a functional context, this should be implemented immutable or at least by storing the file pointer, but it isn't.

Comment: Exactly, hence I created two enumerators. The first being really short lived, but introduced an overhead due to its construction...

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you can tackle your goal from another angle.

That function that would use the remaining enumerator, let's call it `remaining`, presumably it applies to an iteratee to do the processing of the remainder: `remaining |>> iteratee` yielding another iteratee. Let's call that resulting iteratee `iteratee2`... Can you check whether you can get a reference to `iteratee2`? If that's the case, then you can get and process the first byte using a first iteratee `head`, then combine `head` and `iteratee2` through flatMap:

```
val head = Enumeratee.take[Byte](1) &>> Iteratee.foreach[Byte](println)
val processing = for { h <- head; i <- iteratee2 } yield (h, i)
Iteratee.flatten(processing).run
```

If you cannot get a hold of `iteratee2` - which would be the case if your enumerator combines with an enumeratee that you did not implement - then this approach won't work.

Comment: you mean

`val head = Enumeratee.take[Byte](1) &>> Iteratee.getChunks[Byte]`

Comment: @Sadache, that would seem good. Is `getChunks` in 2.0 or 2.0.1 or only in master?

Comment: It is on master.   `def getChunks[E]: Iteratee[E,List[E]] = fold[E, List[E]](Nil) { (els, chunk) => els :+ chunk }`

Comment: Here is a direct definition (that I added) of head (not assuming E is a list-like)

`def head[E]:Iteratee[E,Option[E]] = {

      def step:K[E,Option[E]] = {
        case Input.Empty => Cont(step)
        case Input.EOF => Done(None,Input.EOF)
        case Input.El(e)  => Done(Some(e), Input.Empty)
      }
      Cont(step)
  }`

Comment: Another assuming E is a list-like:
  def head[E,A](implicit p: E => scala.collection.TraversableLike[A, E]):Iteratee[E,Option[A]] = {

      def step:K[E,Option[A]] = {
        case Input.Empty => Cont(step)
        case Input.EOF => Done(None,Input.EOF)
        case Input.El(xs) if ! xs.isEmpty => Done(Some(xs.head), Input.El(xs.tail))
        case Input.El(empty) => Cont(step)
      }
      Cont(step)
  }

Answer (score 1):

Actually we like `Iteratee`s because they compose. So instead of creating multiple `Enumerator`s from your original one, you rather compose the two Iteratees sequentially (read-first and read-rest), and feed it with your single Enumerator.

For this you need a sequential composition method, now I call it `andThen`. Here is a rough implementation. Note that returning the unconsumed input is a bit harsh, maybe could customize behavior with a typeclass based on the Input type. Also it doesn't handle passing the leftover stuff from the first iterator to the second one (Exercise :).

```
object Iteratees {
  def andThen[E, A, B](a: Iteratee[E, A], b: Iteratee[E, B]): Iteratee[E, (A,B)] = new Iteratee[E, (A,B)] {
    def fold[C](
        done: ((A, B), Input[E]) => Promise[C],
        cont: ((Input[E]) => Iteratee[E, (A, B)]) => Promise[C],
        error: (String, Input[E]) => Promise[C]): Promise[C] = {

      a.fold(
        (ra, aleft) => b.fold(
          (rb, bleft) => done((ra, rb), aleft /* could be magicop(aleft, bleft)*/),
          (bcont) => cont(e => bcont(e) map (rb => (ra, rb))),
          (s, err) => error(s, err)
        ),
        (acont) => cont(e => andThen[E, A, B](acont(e), b)),
        (s, err) => error(s, err)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can just use the following:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action { Async {

    val strings: Enumerator[String] = Enumerator("1","2","3","4")
    val takeOne = Cont[String, String](e => e match {
      case Input.El(e) => Done(e, Input.Empty)
      case x => Error("not enough", x)
    })
    val takeRest = Iteratee.consume[String]()
    val firstAndRest = Iteratees.andThen(takeOne, takeRest)

    val futureRes = strings(firstAndRest) flatMap (_.run)

    futureRes.map(x => Ok(x.toString)) // prints (1,234)
  } }

}
```

Comment: See @huynhji's answer, where you can see that actually you don't have to implement `andThen` yourself, since it can be combined using `flatMap`.